# Run Node.js function without calling from client side(React.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function-call

I am building a website with Node/React.
I need functionality like below.
Once the user signs up on my site, I sent a verification email. And store user in DB with "isVerified" field as "false".
If the user doesn't verify in 5 days. I wanna delete that user record.

```
exports.removeUnverifiedUsers = async ( req, res ) => {
//remove user if he created before 5 days and unverified yet.
 ...
}
```

But I have no way to run that function.

Comment: Hey dawnr welcome to stack overflow!  What you would need to do is setup a function that periodically checks your DB for any records that haven't completed that verification.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of Functionality you can use Cron Jobs to call the function and check all the users who doesn't verify in 5 days.  you can use package like `node-schedule` for this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

**Cron Jobs is a Linux command used for scheduling tasks to be executed sometime in the future. This is normally used to schedule a job that is executed periodically**